# Docker build not working for pg_cron extension

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-cron

Looks like the cpio command is not working.

Trying to install pg_cron from https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/15/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pg_cron_15-1.5.1-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm

Attaching the logs here :

```
#8 [3/6] COPY . /app
#8 DONE 0.0s
 
#9 [4/6] RUN ls ./app/cpio
#9 0.354 pg_cron.cpio
#9 DONE 0.4s
 
#10 [5/6] RUN chmod 777 ./app/ && cpio -id  ./app/cpio/pg_cron.cpio &&  ls ./app/cpio
#10 0.399 pg_cron.cpio
#10 DONE 0.4s
```

The base image is postgres:15-alpine

I tries extracting the rpm file, then tried to use cpio command to extract it in the docker build, but cpio command does not work.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your logs. Please update your question to include your actual `Dockerfile`.